# How to union with a distinct column and null rows

Tags: sql-server, union

I am trying to get a list of persons status in SQL Server.

New records are added each day when a person clocks in, so rows do not exist for the current day, however there will be a record of that person clocking in at least one in the table history.

**Example Data**

```
| Name | Status | Date                    |   
|------+--------+-------------------------|  
| Joe  | In     | 2019-09-03 07:56:00.000 |
| Jack | In     | 2019-09-03 06:52:00.000 |
| Joe  | In     | 2019-08-21 07:02:00.000 |
| Jack | In     | 2019-08-14 06:09:00.000 |
| Jane | In     | 2019-08-15 07:38:00.000 |
```

**Example SQL**

```
select name, status
from timeclock
where clockInTime >= dateAdd(day, 0, dateDiff(day, 0, current_timestamp))

union

select name, status
from timeclock
where not exists (?)
```

The first select will incorporate Joe and Jack since hey have clocked in in the last 24 hours.

**Expected Output**

```
| Name | Status |   
|------+--------+    
| Joe  | In     |  
| Jack | In     |  
| Jane | Out    |
```

How do I also select each member only once (distinct), but cast Jane's status as out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like what you want more is something like this:

```
SELECT [Name],
       CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN clockInTime >= dateAdd(day, 0, dateDiff(day, 0, current_timestamp)) THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 'In' ELSE 'OUT' END AS [Status]
FROM timeclock
GROUP BY [Name];
```

This uses conditional aggregation, and only counts the rows after the time.

Comment: This works for this case, I shouldn't have abstracted it so far down... I'm trying to get it to aggregate when `In` could be subbed for `timeclock.status` since there are even more status types (e.g. 'Clock Out Lunch', etc.).